# Select only row which exists based on condition [MariaDB]

Tags: sql, mariadb

I would like to return from database from table *bank* (which contains these columns: user_id, bits, tbits, mbits, time, day, etc.) and I would like to return only one row *if exists* based on user_id something like this:

`` SELECT `user_id`, `bits`, `tbits`, `mbits` FROM `bank` WHERE EXISTS (SELECT `user_id` FROM `bank` WHERE `user_id` = '926364328567933979') ``

*Just a reminder, the user_id is varchar and **not** a number like int.*

But the problem is, that I keep getting all rows, I went through documentation and I couldn't  find the issue. I think I got something wrong, but I really can't find the way to fix this. So in overall how can I return just **one** row based on the condition?

Comment: Do not use `WHERE EXISTS`. Use simple `WHERE `user_id` = '926364328567933979'`

Comment: Are you looking for DISTINCT? SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM bank
WHERE user_id = '926364328567933979'. If not, you should provide sample input and expected outcome since your question is too unclear.

Comment: The condition is true, so all rows will be returned.

Comment: Maybe you can use "in", for example: SELECT `user_id`, `bits`, `tbits`, `mbits` FROM `bank` WHERE `user_id` in (SELECT `user_id` FROM `bank` WHERE `user_id` = '926364328567933979')

Answer (score 1):

You can get only the row with the specified user_id by running:

```sql
SELECT `user_id`, `bits`, `tbits`, `mbits` FROM `bank` WHERE `user_id` = '926364328567933979' LIMIT 1
```